# SSL certificate verify failed with Passenger on OSX using Homebrew, RVM and ruby 2.1

Tags: rvm, passenger, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I get the following error:

```
App 75839 stdout: #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed>
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'"
```

Whenever I try to make a https request with open-uri

Webrick works fine with all https calls.
Unicorn works fine with all https calls.

Certificates locations
    rvm osx-ssl-certs status all

```
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

Open SSL

```
openssl version

OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

I'm starting the server like this:

```
bundle exec passenger start -p 3001 --max-pool-size
```

It also seams to be working on machines using MacPorts.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: You need to show some error and steps to reproduce it, your "question" only states what worked, not what failed.